# Android release key not working

Tags: android, release

I have to update an android application and just got the release key from 2 years ago, I hear it's valid for 24 years.
When I make a release apk with the key and try to upload the SHA1 doesn't match.
The sha1 in the key is correct with the expected SHA1, but my apk is signed with my debug sha1.

Is this problem caused by the key lifespan (under 25 years)?
If so, can I extend this?

Comment: "Is this problem caused by the key lifespan (under 25 years)?" -- probably not. How are you making your release APK? It feels like whatever you are doing is substituting your debug keystore for your production keystore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the keyalias, I thought it didnt matter, but it does...

Answer (score 0):

Key password may get mismatched. So it affects the apk to release.  It's not at all about years and maximum lifespan key is 25 years and you can't extend that. So check whether you have given correct password in release key ie in key alias selection window.